# What markdown template do I need such that output cells in Jupyter notebooks look different from input cells when exporting using nbconvert

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, nbconvert, mkdocs

I am trying to use [mkdocs](http://mkdocs.org/) with [mknotebooks](https://github.com/greenape/mknotebooks) to build a website out of Jupyter Notebook and markdown files. All works well, except, the visual appearance of input and output cells in the resulting html pages is identical, making it hard to understand.

For instance, in a notebook, input and output cells differently as shown below:
[image: correct appearance]

However, when I export to markdown, then to html, they appear similar:
[image: current appearance]

I tried handling this with CSS. However, the `div`s of input and output cells are not of different classes, making it hard to define a different style.

I am currently playing with [nbconvert markdown templates](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/markdown.tpl). However, I cannot figure out, what to modify so output cells appear differently. By default, they are indented by 1 tab space, which it appears is not sufficient to distinguish them when exported to HTML.

My custom template file looks like below:

```html
{% extends 'markdown.tpl' %}

<!-- adds call number to input prompts -->
{% block in_prompt %}
**In [{{ cell.execution_count }}]:**
{% endblock in_prompt %}

<!-- need help - make outputs appear different, perhaps different background cell color? -->
{% block output %}
    {{cell.source}}
{% endblock output %}


{% block markdowncell scoped %} 
{{ cell.source | wrap_text(80) }} 
{% endblock markdowncell %} 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, generate a fenced code block or raw HTML.

## Fenced code block

A fenced code block natively includes a way to assign a class to the code block. Normally the class is expected to be the language of the code contained within the block, but it does not have to be. Therefore, this should do the trick:

````
{% block output %}
``` nb-output
{{cell.source}}
```
{% endblock output %}
````

Note that we have set the class to `nb-output`, which will be set on the `<code>` tag of the HTML (`<pre><code class="nb-output">`).

Now you can define a CSS style for the `nb-output` class. MkDocs already enables the `fenced_code` Markdown extension by default.

## Raw HTML

As the Markdown rules [explain](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

That being the case, there is no mechanism in Markdown to provide styling information (or styling hooks). However, as the rules continue:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

Therefore, in your template, include some raw HTML. Perhaps something like this:

```
{% block output %}
<div class="nb-output">
    {{cell.source}}
</div>
{% endblock output %}
```

Now you can define a CSS style for the `nb-output` class.

Note that as you do not provide the output (the screen shots are not particularly helpful), I can't be certain that a `<div>` is the best tag to use. If you provided the generated HTML for the two examples, then it might be more clear what HTML to use.

For example, Markdown processing is not done inside raw HTML blocks. Therefore, the `cell.source` would not get converted to a proper code block. Perhaps a better approach would be to manually create the code block yourself:

```
{% block output %}
<pre><code class="nb-output">
{{ cell.source|e }}
</code></div>
{% endblock output %}
```

Note that we manually create a code block, (wrapping the `cell.source` in `<pre><code>` tags) while assigning the `nb-output` class to the code block. We also escape the `cell.source` with the `e` filter to ensure that it displays properly in the code block. These are all things that Markdown normally does when creating a code block, minus the class.

Comment: Waylan thanks for this answer. To my surprise, using `cell.source` puts the cell's input code and not its output code. This is strange and I am trying to figure that out before I can test this answer. Meanwhile, I will push up a repo with just this content so it is easier to debug.

Comment: @WayLan can you point me to a resource for the {% block XXX %}  types? I'm trying to write some custom templates, but I don't know what to call those lines and struggling to find them in google.

Comment: @AaronCiuffo the blocks supported in MkDocs' builtin themes are listed [here](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/styling-your-docs/#overriding-template-blocks). If you are using a third party theme, you will need to see the documentation for that theme, or possibly look at the source code of the templates.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming here from Google 4 years later, this question is now answered in the nbconvert documentation. It is actually the example on [how to create a custom template](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html):

````
{% extends 'markdown/index.md.j2' %}

{%- block traceback_line -%}
```output
{{ line.rstrip() | strip_ansi }}
```
{%- endblock traceback_line -%}

{%- block stream -%}
```output
{{ output.text.rstrip() }}
```
{%- endblock stream -%}

{%- block data_text scoped -%}
```output
{{ output.data['text/plain'].rstrip() }}
```
{%- endblock data_text -%}
````